# Can you create a Minesweeper puzzle with 'information crossover'?

Tags: optimization, minesweeper

The object of this puzzle is to construct a Minesweeper grid with a special property. The grid can be any shape, but it must have four labeled squares around the outer edge. Like this:

[image]

The four labeled squares must be labeled A, B, C, D, *in that order going around the outer edge*.

The objective is for a Minesweeper player to be able to conclude that A and C are the same, and B and D are the same, but not be able to conclude anything else. To be specific:

Place numbers in the grid to get a Minesweeper puzzle. This puzzle must have the following properties:

1. There are no safe clicks. That is, for any unnumbered square, there is a solution in which that square is a mine.
2. In any valid solution, A=C and B=D. (A=C means that A has a mine if and only if C does.)
3. A valid solution must satisfy every combination of A=C and B=D simultaneously.

Again, the grid can be any shape. The grid can even have holes in it, but understand that "outer edge" does not include the edge neighboring a hole. A, B, C, D can be placed anywhere along the outer edge, but must be *in that order*. Aim for the smallest grid!

Comment: When you say A=C .. do they count each other for determing number of mines next to ?  So if there are 2 mines next to A. and 1 next to C .. does A show 2, or 3 ?  does C show 1 or 3 ?

Comment: @Ditto What it means is that either A and C both have mines, or neither one does. What number they would show if they didn't have mines is not part of the puzzle.

Comment: Ok, so they are different squares .. they just share a mine/no mine property .. got it :)

Comment: You're asking this to get some help completing your [P=NP Minesweeper proof](http://arstechnica.com/science/2010/08/new-proof-unlocks-answer-to-the-p-versus-np-problemmaybe/), aren't you? ;-)

Comment: Does the definition of the puzzle grid include the number of mines to look for (as in the minesweeper game), or can different solutions use different numbers of mines?

Comment: Also, do the labeled squares need to have an unambiguous ordering? A 1x4 board, for instance, could be labeled many ways, since each square is on both edges. For a concrete example, could either B or D be put one square above C in your sample grid?

Comment: @Lopsy I take it you know the answer and are just posing this as a puzzle an optimization challenge? If not, you should track down the NP-completeness proof for minesweeper consistency, which includes a crossover gadget, or construct one from the planar logic gates.

Comment: @Blckknght The puzzle grid includes the numbers, yes. Of course, the different solutions with A=C and B=D will have different mine placements. &xnor: Yup, I just think it's a fun challenge.

Answer (score 3):

I think I got it now. Using a minesweeper developer program found on [here](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/compurec/Minesweeper.php), you can create, evaluate and try your own board. I have uploaded an image of my solution, or else this would've been a LOT of typing:

> [image]

And an explanation about what you see in the image:

> I've put the 4 labels (A, B, C and D) beside each questionmark where it should be. The red flags mark the spots of pre-discovered bombs.
> Every pair (A-C and B-D) have their own 'wire' as it is called. Then an intersection to let these signals cross eachother, and arive at the other side.
> For the first rule: there are no safe clicks, in all possible solutions this setup has got, any unnumbered square has been a mine at least once.
> In èvery solution of this setup: it covers the A=C and B=D requirement. So both the second and third rule are covered too.

---

**Discarded answers (Just for comment-reference)**

> ```
> 1) .A   2)  A  3) AB
>     1 .    D2B    DC
>   D1.1B     C
>   . 1
>     C.
> ```

Comment: Maybe I made the rules unclear. Rule 2 says "In any valid solution, A=C and B=D." Your first option breaks this because there is a solution where A and D have mines and B and C don't. Your second option breaks this because anything is a solution. Is it clear how Rule 2 works now?

Comment: @Lopsy Ok, I think it is clear now, let me (and others) work on a possible solution

Comment: I don't think your new answer implies that A=C and B=D. For example, you could have A with a mine and the bottom-right dot has a mine, but C does not.

Comment: If A is a mine, the dot next to it is not (because of the 1). And there is a solution in which C is a mine and the dot next to it is not. This is typically that moment of the 'last guess' ([here](https://global3.memecdn.com/minesweeper-rage_o_682077.jpg))

Comment: No, @KSmarts is right. Rule #2's statement of "in any valid solution" does not say "there is a combination that satisfies A=C, B=D", it says "the only possible combinations satisfy A=C, B=D".

Comment: What I'm saying is that there is a valid solution where A is a mine and the dot next to C is a mine, so C is not a mine. So A$\neq$C.

Comment: @Lopsy I hope you have the solution to this problem and not just wondering if there is one. Because I do not see one valid solution that satisfies every combination of A=C and B=D simultaneously. But if you look at your comment "...all 4 mine-settings of A, B, C, D satisfying A=C and B=D extend to a solution", my puzzle is a possible solution. Therefor my question: do you know the answer?

Comment: I know a solution. But it was pretty dang hard for me to find one! And the solution I have is nowhere near optimal.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid board. It can't have any solution at the four unknowns just four squares to the left of B. Also if D is mine, C will also need to be a mine following the diagonal from D to C. Then A will also be safe.

Comment: @justhalf Ah, yes indeed, I see what you mean. I have to place the ? correctly and put the right numbers in the blocks. I've forgotten a few. Look at [this pdf explaining logic ports in minesweeper](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/minesw/minesw.pdf). The 'signal' from left to right is v -> r but I had the D on the v' (which is the opposite of the signal v).

Comment: Now it looks correct. +1

Comment: Btw can we adapt this to make ABCD on the outer edge of the board to fulfill all the requirements?

Comment: @justhalf I think ABCD are just about on the edge of the board. But be my guest if you can optimize it even further, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably twisting the rules a bit, but here goes. "The grid can be any shape". Well, my grid is a *torus!* (And it kinda looks like a swastika, but let's ignore that.)

```
C+A D
  1 +
D1+1B
+ 1
B C+A
```

The labels are shown twice to indicate where the grid "wraps around". The grid itself uses 11 squares.

I realize that this probably isn't what is intended, but I thought of this and decided to post it while working on a "real" answer.

---

**Pre-edit answer:**
How about this:

> ```
> 1A1
> D B
> 1C1
> ```

The space in the middle is a "hole". If A has a mine, then B and D do not, which means that C does. Similarly, if A does not have a mine, then B and D do, so C does not. Thus, this satisfies all three conditions.

It uses a 3x3 grid, with a total of 8 squares.

Comment: @Ian Macdonald and KSmarts: I think Lopsy means that for évery combination a solution has to exist. Both AC and BD have mines, AC have mines and BD are clear, AC are clear and BD have mines, both AC and BD are clear

Comment: @JBSregath: no, not quite. The reason why he claimed your answer did not follow rule 2 was that there existed a valid combination of ABCD that did not satisfy rule 2. No such rule-breaking combination exists in this answer (or mine).

Comment: @Ian Macdonald: And rule #3: For any mine-setting of A, B, C, and D that satisfies A=C and B=D, this setting extends to a solution of the whole grid. This means a valid solution has to exist for each of these settings: both AC and BD mines, AC mines and BD clear, AC clear and BD mines, both AC and BD clear

Comment: @JBSregath I can see how it might mean that. I'll wait to hear from Lopsy, though, because that makes it a lot harder.

Comment: Yes, JBSregath is correct. Feel free to edit the puzzle (I am on a phone which makes editing very annoying.)

Comment: @Lopsy, so you're saying that a valid solution *must* exist simultaneously for *all* combinations of A=C, B=D?

Comment: Yes Ian that's right. Of course the solutions will be different for each of the four combinations with A=C and B=D.

Comment: 3-dimensional minesweeper?! :O

Comment: @IanMacDonald Nope. A torus, in the sense that I'm using it, is a 2-dimensional surface. It is often represented by an embedding in 3-space, the shape of which is also called a torus, and is probably what you are thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to clarify what a "hole" is.

> ```
>   A
> D   B
>   C
> ```

This satisfies the puzzle's requirements.

> There are no safe spaces; all of the spaces are mines. Because none of the spaces are adjacent to each other, none of them can be a "numbered square"; the value of this number would be 0, making it an empty (or safe) space.

Comment: This could be a solution indeed, but there might be a possibility this is not allowed because none of the sides are touching, thus not a minesweeper puzzle. I'll leave it up to Lopsy

Comment: It follows the rules laid out in the challenge and it follows the rules of Minesweeper as they are modified to include holes. It's really just a question of what makes a "smaller grid". 4 non-hole squares is smaller than 8 non-hole squares, but they take up more space if you include the holes in the calculation.

Comment: How does this not have the "anything is a solution" problem that @JBSregath's second answer does?

Comment: @KSmarts: See the second spoiler block.

Comment: The intention of rule 3 is that there should be a solution where (for example) A and C are both mines and B and D are both safe. That is, all 4 mine-settings of A, B, C, D satisfying A=C and B=D extend to a solution. I see now that I phrased this rule badly, sorry to the solvers so far.

Comment: The status of ABCD is unknown at the start of the game (by how minesweeper works). The possibility of the "all mines" solution means that none of the squares are "safe," regardless of whether they actually have mines or not.